# How to draw image like free hand tool on pdf file page in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, uitouch

I have applied [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) link to display pdf file on the ipad with CGPDF classes and now i need to draw an image on the same pdf file's loaded page. I am using

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) 
    {
        //drawImage.image = nil;
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
        return;
    }
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    //  CGFloat x = self.view.frame.size.width-100;
    //  CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height-100;

    //  [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)];
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    mouseMoved++;
    if (mouseMoved == 10) 
    {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) 
    {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }
    if(!mouseSwiped) 
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

for using the freehand tool and i am able to draw image on the view if i am not loading the pdf file. but i am not able to overwrite the image on the pdf page. Can anybody help me with some solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to save it to the PDF file as an annotation or do you just want do display freehand drawings over the PDF page?

Comment: Yes,I want to draw the image as free hand and then also to save it to the pdf file as an annotation.

Comment: Do you have found it? I am looking for it too.

Comment: @Amitabh : DrawImage is an imageview,and also this is not answer so better you write it as comment and delete your post from answer.That may give you negative marking.

Comment: @Sarah: I am extremely sorry to post my query as an answer again, but there is no link on the page to add a comment to the thread. Please help me out on how to go about declaring the drawImage object of the imageView class. Thank you.

Comment: ya sure.I have just declared it in .h file like UIImageView *DrawImage; You can tell me what u want to do or just create a new question by selecting the "Ask Question Button" and pass the link to that in the comment,so that even you can get answers from experts too.

Comment: @Amitabh: I posted some links in your post,just refer that.